# Make back/forward work on paginated lists

Tags: feature-request, pagination, back-button

When viewing a list of my own questions, if I switch to page 2 of the list I can't go back to page 1 by clicking the "Back" button in the browser.

I understand this is by design, but can the back button be made to work in this case please?

Comment: I'd love to see this work, it's always bugged the crap out of me. It's like that for all paginated lists, not just question lists (e.g. activity in profile, etc.) Workaround in the mean time is to make sure to always open links in a new tab (ctrl-click on Windows Chrome, at least) to preserve your location in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because those page buttons actually execute an ajax request in stead of a whole page request.
I wouldn't say that's actually "by design" as it's possible to make the back button of your browser behave like you want it to (gmail does this all over the place).